# Can you use setReduxObject and selectReduxObject in the same .jsx page?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I am learning Redux and I have deviated from the instructor's code. I am trying to convert my code from context & state into Redux.

Is it advisable to use setReduxObject (`setCategoriesMap` in my code) and selectReduxObject (`selectCategoriesMap` in my code) in the same .jsx page? Are there any concerns around this?

Thanks!

My code:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { getCategoriesAndDocuments } from "../../utils/firebase/firebase.utils";
import { setCategoriesMap } from "../../store/categories/categories.action";
import { selectCategoriesMap } from "../../store/categories/categories.selector";

import Category from "../../components/category/category.component";

const Shop = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCategoriesMap = async () => {
      const categories = await getCategoriesAndDocuments();
      dispatch(setCategoriesMap(categories));
    };
    getCategoriesMap();
  }, []);

  const categoriesMap = useSelector(selectCategoriesMap);

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(categoriesMap).map((key) => {
        const products = categoriesMap[key];
        return <Category key={key} title={key} products={products} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the default approach, nothing to be concerned about.

As soon as you're using `getCategoriesAndDocuments` the same way in another component though, it's better to move this to an async action creator.

Could even do it for this component already to improve separation of concerns. The component does not necessarily need to be involved with firebase, its job is display logic. Wether the data comes from firebase or localStorage or some graphQL server should not matter.